# Navigate to a slide within same ppt without going fullscreen?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a Microsoft Office 2007 ppt file where there are multiple hyperlinks available and I want to navigate to the hyperlinks without entering fullscreen(pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>). I tried using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ mouse click. But doesn't work. How could I navigate from one slide to another specific slide using a hyperlink or action like in an HTML page without going fullscreen? Is there any key combinations or shortcuts available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click the linked shape, choose Open Hyperlink.

Comment: How do I go back to the previous slide after clicking the Open Hyperlink.?

Comment: Short of putting a "Previously viewed slide" link on each slide you plan to link to (and I'm not certain THAT would work), I don't know of a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

#### How can I navigate from one slide to another specific slide using a hyperlink?

- <kbd>Tab</kbd>

  Go to the first or next hyperlink on a slide.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

  Go to the last or previous hyperlink on a slide.
- <kbd>Enter</kbd> (while a hyperlink is selected)

  Perform the "mouse click" behavior of the selected hyperlink.

Source [PowerPoint 2010 Shortcuts](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/PowerPoint_2010.html)

The shortcuts are the same for [PowerPoint 2007](https://support.office.com/en-GB/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-PowerPoint-2007-32b35aab-8ce2-4b1e-b518-bd278b0d3fac):

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But, I'm using MS office 2007 the `Enter` key doesn't work. It doesn't navigate to the hyperlinked slide while it's highlighted.

Comment: According to [Keyboard shortcuts for PowerPoint 2007](https://support.office.com/en-GB/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-PowerPoint-2007-32b35aab-8ce2-4b1e-b518-bd278b0d3fac) the behaviour should be the same as for 2010.

Comment: Yes, but it works only when the ppt is running (i.e. Fullscreen mode). The problem is when I go fullscreen by pressing F5 the slides in the left pane are not visible. So again I have to press F5 and come out of full screen to get to some other random slide.